# decorator action in generics

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i need to add action decorator from rest_framework.decorators to view on generics

views.py

```py
class AnswerDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdminOnly]
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer

    @action(['POST'], detail=True)
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        answer = self.get_object()
        author = request.user
        serializer = AnswerReviewSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            try:
                answer_review = AnswerReview.objects.get(answer=answer, author=author)
                answer_review.delete()
                message = 'disliked'
            except AnswerReview.DoesNotExist:
                AnswerReview.objects.create(answer=answer, author=author)
                message = 'liked'
            return Response(message, status=200)
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('answers/', views.AnswerCreateView.as_view()),
    path('answers/<int:pk>/', views.AnswerDetailView.as_view()),
    path('comments/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view()),
    path('comments/<int:pk>/', views.CommentDetailView.as_view()),
    path('answers/<int:pk>/like/', views.AnswerDetailView.like),
]
```

i've tried on ModelViewSet and it works but how can i do it on generics?

also i need my urls for like button look like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('answers/<int:pk>/like/', <view>),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**@action** doesn't work with **GenericAPIView**. it's only working with **ViewSet**. I will suggest you should use GenericViewSet.